# Working with RequireJS multipage and page template

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs

i'm starting with requireJS and need some help to proceed with its implementation.

My site is built following the defaults:

```
    header.html (always the same, containing the requiredjs script tag) 

    $pageMain       (always variable - $pageAbout, $pageContact...) 

    footer.html (always the same)
```

I need to load specific js file in different pages from my site, but i have only one header which contains the tag to set my required files.

`<script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>`

When my page is $pageAbout i need to load $pageAbout.js instead $pageMain.js
I'm still not able to do this.

Checking the https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage# i understood how it works, but in my case, i coudn't do it because i specify the script tag only once in the header.html

Any suggestion ? 
I don't know if i was clear in my question. Please let me know to better explain.

Answer (score 1):

There are various solutions here, depending on what you can easily edit.

- You could change the script tag in the header, based on the current page. I am assuming from your description that this is not possible.
- If you have to always load the same `js/main` script, you could use that as a switch between different page-specific modules:

  ```
  // js/main.js
  define(function() {
      var pageId = getPageId();
      require('js/' + pageId);
  });
  ```

  This depends on being able to get the page id when the header loads - either through a JS variable you can set before the header is loaded, or by parsing the URL, or through some other means.
- You can simply drop the script tag from the header and include it in the variable body of your page. Script tags can appear anywhere in the document.
- You could drop the `data-main` attribute from the header script tag (so that the header just loads the RequireJS library), then have a script tag in your page body to load the page-specific module:

  ```
  <script> require('js/pageAbout'); </script>
  ```

Any of these should work - the last two are probably simplest. The RequireJS docs are very prescriptive, but there are many paths to a working implementation - you don't have to do it the recommended way.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer nrabinowitz ! The solution with the method to switch the page IDs looks great. I'll give a try and tomorrow I post again with feedback!